# mysql add query with null value

Tags: mysql

I have mysql query

```
SELECT
    ju.ID,
    ju.JENIS_USAHA,
    COALESCE(TOTAL_PEMBERI, 0) AS TOTAL_PEMBERI,
    COALESCE(OUTLET_PEMBERI, 0) AS OUTLET_PEMBERI,
    COALESCE(TOTAL_PENERIMA, 0) AS TOTAL_PENERIMA,
    COALESCE(OUTLET_PENERIMA, 0) AS OUTLET_PENERIMA,
    COALESCE(OUTLET_PEMBERI + OUTLET_PENERIMA, 0) AS SEMUA
```

the problem is when OUTLET_PEMBERI not null and OUTLET_PENERIMA null (or vise versa), SEMUA will show 0. How to solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `COALESCE` on both terms separately:

```
SELECT
    ju.ID,
    ju.JENIS_USAHA,
    COALESCE(TOTAL_PEMBERI, 0) AS TOTAL_PEMBERI,
    COALESCE(OUTLET_PEMBERI, 0) AS OUTLET_PEMBERI,
    COALESCE(TOTAL_PENERIMA, 0) AS TOTAL_PENERIMA,
    COALESCE(OUTLET_PENERIMA, 0) AS OUTLET_PENERIMA,
    COALESCE(OUTLET_PEMBERI, 0) + COALESCE(OUTLET_PENERIMA, 0) AS SEMUA
FROM ...
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, and you really want a zero value when *either* term in the summation be `NULL`, then just leave your code as is.